# I get an error called The constructor main(Display) is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse

this is class main

```
        package com.First.Game;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {

    public static Display f = new Display();
    public static int width =600;
    public static int height = 400;
    public static void main(String args[]){
f=new Display();    

f.setSize(width, height);
f.setResizable(false);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setTitle("Sticky Zombies");
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
System.out.println("STICKY ZOMBIES is running on a main window");




    }
}
```

and this is class Display

```
        package com.First.Game;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JFrame{
public main panel;

public Display(){
    panel= new main(this);


}
}
```

im a begginer and i really need help
i basicly copied some code exactly from what i saw and in the video i watched, he could run it perfectly(this is not the complete code of what i watched)

Comment: Where is your main method?

Answer (score 3):

You have **not defined any constructor for your class main.** In such cases your class will have **only default constructor**(zero argument constructor). But in your code `panel= new main(this);` you are trying to call **parametrized constructor which does not exist**. Hence you get the error.

Replace it with this : `panel= new main();`

OR

define a constructor explicitly in your main class as follows :

```
public main(Display disp) {
this.display = disp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.First.Game;

public class Display {

public main panel;

          public Display(){
             panel= new main(this);
           }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


       Display obj = new Display();

   }
}
```

And change the name of the class `main` to something else

Comment: This still won't compile, see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15987694/90874